# Looking Regex to find and replace first and last character of each line, preferably Visual Studio or C#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I have a list of urls like so:

```
/best-family-accommodation-for-holidays-with-kids/
/priority-privilege-membership/
/category/best-family-destination/
/best-family-destination/family-holidays-asia/
...
```

I would like to replace the first character / with Empty and the last character / with a comma on each line.

Just don't know Regex well enough to do this with as little sleep as I currently am on.

Comment: why regex? this case be achieved using simple string methods. If extremely needed then here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aW4dC8/1)

Comment: Thanks user3218114, regex101 looks like a great tool too ;)

Comment: But RegEx would be much slower in your case since you know exactly that the character that should be replaced is in the beginning and end of each line. Therefore string.Tim is the much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

May you try something like this

```
str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1).Insert(str.Length-1,",").Remove(0, 1).Insert(0, " ");
```

i tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some string manipulation on each item in the list, copy the manipulated strings to a temporary list (as you will be manipulating within a foreach loop), finally replacing the original list with the contents of the temporary list.

Start by creating a couple of extension methods that replace the first and last occurrence of a string in a string, e.g.

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static String ReplaceFirstOccurrence(this string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
        if (pos < 0) return text;

        return replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    }

    public static String ReplaceLastOccurrence(this string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.LastIndexOf(search);
        if (pos < 0) return text;

        return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace;
    }
};
```

Now, by iterating over the list of URL's you could then manipulate the string to replace the first and last "/" with a "" and a ",".
You will need to add the manipulated string to a temporary list because you won't be allowed to replace the current item within a iteration.
Finally, replace the original list with the contents of the temporary list that contains the strings you want.
E.g.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<String>
        {
            "/best-family-accommodation-for-holidays-with-kids/",
            "/priority-privilege-membership/",
            "/category/best-family-destination/",
            "/best-family-destination/family-holidays-asia/"
        };

        var tmpList = new List<String>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // Manipulate the strings in the list and add them
            // to a temporary list
            var newItem = item.ReplaceFirstOccurrence("/", "");
            newItem = newItem.ReplaceLastOccurrence("/", ",");
            tmpList.Add(newItem);
        }

        // Replace the contents of the original list
        // with the contents of the temporary list
        list.Clear();
        tmpList.ForEach(t => { list.Add(t); });

        // Don't need the temporary list anymore
        tmpList.Clear();
    }
```

This will leave a trailing comma on the last item in the list, but I'll leave that up to you to do.